# High degree polynomial with complex roots only (no real roots)

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing, roots, multinomial-theorem

Suppose a given polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1x^1+...+a_{2n}x^{2n}$ for $n\in{N}$.

How can I show that if all roots are complex? note that all coefficients are real. I actually need the solution for multinomials with $m$ variables but for simplicity, I have chosen a simple polynomial.

Comment: Using discriminants?

Comment: Descartes' rule of signs should point you to a sure-fire procedure.

Comment: @saulspatz See my comment above? Even in floating-point arithmetic, negation doesn't incur any extra error.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that all roots are complex. Presumably, you're asking how to show that there _are no real roots_, which is a different question and I believe much more difficult to tackle in general.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Somehow I read the question as asking for all real roots, rather than no real roots.

Comment: [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) gives you a terminating algorithm to count the number of real roots. In particular you can determine if that number is zero.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Consider $x^4-x^2+1$.  Descartes' rule of signs says there are an ever number of positive roots, not exceeding $2$, and an even number of negative roots, not exceeding $2$.  We cannot conclude from that no roots are real.

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah, I'd figured out why Descartes won't work in general here.

Comment: @saulspatz  Descartes rule of signs does work, but it has to be combined with [Vincent's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation#Vincent's_and_related_theorems) to effectively bracket each of the roots. The bracketing of the roots gives, in particular, their number.

Comment: @logarithm that was really helpful; many thanks. can I use this theory (or something similar) in multinomials?

Comment: @logarithm That looks like a very interesting article.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the key ideas here is to express the polynomial as a sum of squares. If there is no value of the variable(s) for which the squares are all zero, then there are no real roots. I have linked below to various statements that such polynomials can be decomposed into sums of squares, but have found limited material on effective methods for doing this.

There is plenty of information and links in the [Wikipedia article on positive polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_polynomial)

For your single variable case the article states that any non-negative polynomial over $\mathbb R$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares of polynomials over $\mathbb R$. In fact this is easy to see as the roots then have to come in complex conjugate pairs and give a factor of the form $(x-a)^2+b^2$ for each pair of roots $a\pm bi$. Then the identity $$(p^2+q^2)(r^2+s^2)=(pr+qs)^2+(ps-qr)^2$$ shows that the product of such factors is itself a sum of two squares. This, of course, does not help unless there is an effective way of finding a decomposition into a sum of squares in the first place.

The multi-variable case was [Hilbert's 17th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem), solved by Artin, who showed that a non-negative polynomial was the sum of squares of rational functions. Again, this excludes real solutions if you avoid the squares being simultaneously zero. Again, I think this is non-constructive.

The question of effective methods seems to be addressed in [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3569/polynomials-that-are-sums-of-squares) and answers. See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9073/when-does-positive-imply-sum-of-squares?rq=1), which has some material on polynomials, and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8579/are-all-polynomial-inequalities-deducible-from-the-trivial-inequality) also.

See further [Polynomial Sums of Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_SOS) and there is a paper (in English) [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~vicki/preprint/PsdSosSurvey.pdf).